# How to automate an excel file to make graphs and then automatically email them as well

Tags: java, automation, powerbi

I currently have a Java program that outputs data into an excel file. While I am not hell-bent on using excel, my requirements are to process the data, make graphs, and then email those graphs. I am looking to automate the entire process. How can I achieve the same?

I tried using PowerBi and Power Automate tools but am not finding a definitive way.

Comment: Hello and Welcome.
Any chance you can ask a more focused question? There are many ways to solve your problem. The most appropriate technology for you will depend on many factors that are specific to you and your proposed deployment environment.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

So without knowing too many of the specifics of your ask I would say that it may be worth looking into creating Microsoft Excel scripts that would generate charts from inputted data. You could then used the "Run Script" in the excel modules to automate the process. Then send the results in an automated email. So your flow would look like: Run when file is modified or scheduled if its a regular drop -> Run Excel Script -> Send Email with outputs.

You can see the example with pictures and instructions at this link:
[Flow with Script example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/email-images-chart-table)

Hope this sets you on the right path at least!

-Sean

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Python, and the excellent [xlwings](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/) library for integrating with Excel.